# SharePoint Framework: Do we have to care about the Minimal Download Strategy (MDS)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, client-side-rendering, mds

The [Minimal Download Strategy](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/minimal-download-strategy-overview) ([MDS](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/optimize-page-performance-in-sharepoint)) used to cause lots of problems in combination with JSLink, Script Editor Webparts etc. At least when you don't write code [to handle MDS properly](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/modify-sharepoint-components-for-mds).

Is MDS something we have to care about when using the SharePoint Framework to develop client-side solutions?

Answer (score 2):

MDS was one of the (very good, only lacked proper education) JS features killed

Too bad, always had fun to he future on/of on presenters non-locked laptops in lunch break session

The MDS code itself was one of the better I 'seen, clearly done by someone who knew Front-end ( a whole let better compared to todays code )

Comment: Good riddance. Nobody ever understood it (documentation issue) and turned it off. In a sense it was conflicting with the approach "now every web developer can do SharePoint because it's just web dev!". Let's see how all works out in SPFx. Do you have any documentation about MDS being discontinued? Or is this by observation?